# How to use the SUM function on a specific table two times and then make a deduction

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible in the same SQL query to use the SUM function for different occasions;

For example, lets use the below SQL table called 'TEMPTABLE'

On the table you can see that the item with ITEM_ID=001 appears three times. On the first two times appears with the OCCASION 1 and on the last one with the OCCASION 2.

What I want to do is to make a SUM on THE QTY column that have the same ITEM_ID=001 and OCCASION=1 AND then deduct the SUM of the QTY with the OCCASION 2 and ITEM_ID=001

```
TEMPTABLE
ITEM_ID  QTY  OCCASION
--------------------
001       2    1
002       3    1
001       4    1
003       2    1
001       1    2
```

For the ITEM_CODE=001 the result should be (2+4)-1=5.

Is it possible to do that with one query?

Comment: show your exepected output and also add some test data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  ITEM_ID, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN OCCASION = 1 THEN QTY ELSE 0 END)
        - SUM(CASE WHEN OCCASION = 2 THEN QTY ELSE 0 END)
FROM    TEMPTABLE
GROUP BY ITEM_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below code. Its working fine in SQL Server 2012.

```
DECLARE @TEMPTABLE TABLE (ITEM_ID Char(5), QTY int, OCCASION int)

INSERT INTO @TEMPTABLE
(ITEM_ID,QTY,OCCASION)
VALUES
(001,2,1),
(002,3,1),
(001,4,1),
(003,2,1),
(001,1,2)


SELECT  ITEM_ID, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN OCCASION = 1 THEN QTY ELSE 0 END)-
        SUM(CASE WHEN OCCASION = 2 THEN QTY ELSE 0 END) AS Total
FROM    @TEMPTABLE
GROUP BY ITEM_ID
```

Output:

```
ITEM_ID Total
1       5
2       3
3       2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select item_id, sum(qty*(3 - 2*occasion)) 
from table 
group by item_id
```

Comment: Down vote care to comment.  Did you try this?  Not wrong just because you don't understand it.

Comment: @gofr1 You missed performant.    I think it will be faster than the case based solutions.